# Get the average of a list for each key in a dict

Tags: python

I have a defaultdict that maps names to a list of scores.  I need to work out the average scores of students.

```
scores = {"Aaron" : ["1" , "3" , "4"] , "Joe" : ["3" , "7" , "2"] , "Bob" : ["7" , "4" , "8"]}
```

How can I get the averages in a new dict?

```
averages = {"Aaron" : 2.7 , "Joe" : 4 , "Bob" : 13.7}
```

Comment: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You are asking for details on putting together the solution as you have envisioned it, rather than asking how to solve the problem you're actually trying to solve. In fact all the interim data structures you want help to create are completely unnecessary. What you actually want to do is take one dictionary and create another from it. That's all.

Comment: Why didn't you answer like that then?

Comment: I don't feel that my comment is a complete answer and wouldn't want it evaluated as such. Which is what comments are for...

Answer (score 2):

Convert each value from a string to a float, take the average, and build a new dict.

```
scores = {"Aaron" : ["1" , "3" , "4"] , "Joe" : ["3" , "7" , "2"] , "Bob" : ["7" , "4" , "8"]}
averages = {key: sum(float(i) for i in value) / len(value) for key, value in scores.items()}
```